circular import of classes
I am new to object oriented programming (and to python). Why is the following code a bad object design? What is the nice design that won't cause the circular import here?
I want the classes to communicate but the use of first inside of the second and vice versa causes NameError: name 'Board' is not defined.
Or is it a problem of python and using a different import would help?
import numpy as np

class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self, col: int, row: int):
        self.__col = col
        self.__row = row

    def get_col(self):
        return self.__col

    def get_row(self):
        return self.__row

    def c_on_board(self, board: Board):
        existing = board.get_all_existing()
        return [self.__col, self.__row] in existing

class Board:
    def __init__(self, mat: np.matrix):
        self.__mat = mat

    def get_value(self, c: Coordinates):
        return self.__mat[c.get_col()][c.get_row()]

    def get_all_existing(self):
        A = np.array(self.__mat)
        existing = np.argwhere(A != np.nan)
        return existing

I tried to have separate .py files for both classes and import them using from classes.board import Board and so on but the issue is still there, only this time it raises ImportError: cannot import name 'Board' from partially initialized module 'classes.Board' (most likely due to a circular import)

Where are the circular imports?

Find related issues by searching 'python circular import' for how to build your code.

This is not a circular import.  This is an invalid reference.  Python is trying to find Board in the function c_on_board before Board is defined.

Beside the pont, but you don't need to write getters and setters in Python. For this example, you can just use bare attributes, and in your real code if you want to prevent setting/deleting, you can use a property.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. There are a lot of similar questions, so it'd help to write a title that better describes the problem and makes it clear what you're asking. For a start, I tried to rename it to "circular dependency of classes", but there's already a C++ question called that. Check out [ask] for tips, and you can [edit].

The issue you are seeing is that you have tightly coupled the Coordinates class to the Board class.  In programming we want to avoid coupling because a change to one class must be accounted for in all of the other classes that are coupled to it.
Managing your code (especially large code bases) is much easier when each class is independent from the others.  Let's ask the question "why does Coordinates need to know about Board?"  It doesn't!  The coordinates simply contain the row and column.  That is all it needs to do.
Instead, we can move the check of if a coordinate is valid to the Board class.  If the coordinate is not valid, you raise an error to let the user know what happened.
import numpy as np

class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self, col: int, row: int):
        self._col = col
        self._row = row

    def get_col(self):
        return self._col

    def get_row(self):
        return self._row


class Board:
    def __init__(self, mat: np.matrix):
        self._mat = mat

    def get_value(self, c: Coordinates):
        if not self._coord_is_in_board(c):
            raise ValueError('Coordinate is not within the Board boundaries')
        return self._mat[c.get_col()][c.get_row()]

    def get_all_existing(self):
        return np.argwhere(self._mat != np.nan)
    
    def _coord_is_in_board(self, c: Coordinates) -> False:
        n_rows, n_cols = self._mat.shape
        row_valid = (0 <= c.get_row() < n_rows)
        col_valid = (0 <= c.get_col() < n_cols)
        return row_valid and col_valid


Is "independent" the right word? That would mean Board doesn't know about Coordinates either, no? I'm not sure what the right word would be, but the idea is that classes shouldn't be mutually dependent, while they can still depend on each other in a tree shape.

@wjandrea it is right, if Board didn't know about Coordinates then it would be easier to update each independently. But sometimes a dependency is needed, so you try to make it one-way so that Coordinates is independent of Board but Board depends on Coordinates

Yes, in this example, Board is coupled to Coordinates.  If you want to decouple them, tne you would implement an interface, make Coordinates adhere to the interface, and the Board.get_value method accepts objects that duck-type to the interface as well.

If Coordinates must be an object, then it makes sense for each instance of Board to have Coordinates. But if it's a 1:1 relationship, it might make sense to build coordinates functionality directly into Board as a member,
